# The message inscribed on the One Ring. What does this line mean?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring, tolkiens-legendarium

The second last line of the message reads:

> One ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

What exactly does this mean?

By *them*, I'm assuming it's referring to the humans, elves and dwarves Sauron gave rings of power.

By ...*and in the darkness bind them*, does he mean to bind them to his will like slaves, or to trap them in some way/place? Were the elves and dwarves supposed to end up [ringwraiths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazg%C3%BBl) like the humans?

What is *the darkness*?

Maybe no explanation is ever given, I'm just curious. For a long time I thought it read *and in the darkness BITE them*. Which I assumed meant to kill them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the inscription of the One Ring, what or who does "them all" refer to?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58511/in-the-inscription-of-the-one-ring-what-or-who-does-them-all-refer-to)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. It's asking what the darkness refers to and none of the answers explicitly speak to that point.

Comment: Agreed with @Richard - I'll be using my un-dupe hammer here if this gets closed :)

Comment: Hooray for Satan!

Comment: @Daft - You don't hear that a lot. Unless you've had a very odd upbrining.

Comment: @Richard my parents enjoyed heavy metal.

Comment: @Daft - Iron Maiden?  Excellent! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE3bc8rCy6Q

Comment: "Them all" clearly refers to all the rings.  "In the darkness" clearly refers to the metaphorical darkness of Sauron's rule.

Comment: That is not the last line of the poem, but the second-to-last line. The last line is `In the land of Mordor where the shadows lie`.

Comment: @trysis cheers, I'll updated the question now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's pretty clear (from the Silmarillion and other texts) that the "darkness" is intended semi-metaphorically. It refers to Sauron's evil as creating a figurative darkness over all he commands. Note also that his domains are always described as dark and brooding, even during the daytime.

> *Hail Eärendil, bearer of light before the Sun and Moon! Splendour of
>   the Children of Earth, **star in the darkness**, jewel in the sunset,
>   radiant in the morning!'*  <sub><sup>- Silmarillion</sup></sub>

...

> 'Four days and nights, and on into a fifth, we rode from the Black
>   Stone,' he said. 'And lo! **in the darkness of Mordor** my hope rose; for
>   in that gloom the Shadow Host seemed to grow stronger and more
>   terrible to look upon.  <sub><sup>- LOTR : The Return of the King</sup></sub>

...

> The Men of Númenor were settled far and wide on the shores and
>   seaward regions of the Great Lands, but for the most part they fell
>   into evils and follies. **Many became enamoured of the Darkness and the
>   black arts;** some were given over wholly to idleness and ease, and some
>   fought among themselves, until they were conquered in their weakness
>   by the wild men. `It is not said that evil arts were ever practised in
>   Gondor, or that the Nameless One was ever named in honour there  <sub><sup>- LOTR : The Two Towers</sup></sub>

...

> Gandalf fell silent, gazing eastward from the porch to the far peaks
>   of the Misty Mountains, at whose great roots the peril of the world
>   had so long lain hidden. He sighed. There I was at fault,' he said.
>   I was lulled by the words of Saruman the Wise; but I should have
>   sought for the truth sooner, and our peril would now be less.' We
>   were all at fault,' said Elrond, and **but for your vigilance the
>   Darkness, maybe, would already be upon us.** But say on!'   <sub><sup>- LOTR : The Fellowship of the Ring</sup></sub>

Comment: You might also contrast with the *light* of Aman, and the *light* of the secret fire. Plus, contrast with the *outer darkness*, and the *darkness* of Morgoth.

Comment: @Lexible - You're not wrong, but I concluded that after a while I was simply flogging a dead horse by piling reference onto reference.

Comment: @Richard You can never have enough references :)

Comment: Note also that in the War of the Ring Sauron exported **literal** darkness over the lands he intended to conquer...for a little while at any rate.

Comment: @Richard to make this a more complete answer, you may want to add a TL;DR or something like "The line refers to Sauron's ultimate goal - bringing the other rings of power under his own dominion."

Comment: This is a great answer Richard, much appreciated. Would you have any idea as to what **bind them** means? Did Sauron intend to turn all of recipients of the rings into ringwraiths?

Comment: @Daft - It's reasonably clear that the intention was to control the will of those that were wearing the rings, binding them to the will of the wielder of the One Ring.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1kvf1l/eli5_what_does_the_one_ring_actually_do/cbtig6k

Comment: @AndreKR that's actually a great explanation of what the One Ring was intended for. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

One Ring to bring them all - surely this means to tie all of the Rings of Power to the One Ring, and bind the holders to Sauron's will?

Comment: Welcome to scifi.stackexchange! I actually find it quite plausible what you're saying (myself, I've always read it that _them_ refers to the  Rings, not the peoples), but as you have phrased the post it's not so much an answer as a counter-question, and thus should rather be a _comment_ – unless you can rephrase it and add some supporting references.